# Generate Margin-Top size depending on page location - Fixed Off Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I'd like to have an element follow the user down the page, like a fixed position div, however this is not possible with the foundation Off Canvas Menu.

Is there a way to capture the distance that the page has scrolled in pixels and output it as the `margin-top:` style on a specific div?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.scrollY` to get the scrolled distance, then you could use jQuery:

```
$("#myElement").css("margin-top", window.scrollY);
```

or use plain JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("myElement").style.marginTop = window.scrollY;
```